# SQL peak value per day

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a following table:

```
   id |  booking_time       | art   | weight
   ---+---------------------+-------+------
    1 | 2017-06-18 10:34:09 | wood  |  1000
    2 | 2017-06-18 11:31:11 | wood  |  2000
    3 | 2017-06-18 14:11:25 | stone |  1000
    4 | 2017-06-18 16:47:37 | wood  |  -300
    5 | 2017-06-19 10:49:21 | wood  |   100
    6 | 2017-06-19 12:41:02 | wood  | -1000
    7 | 2017-06-19 12:49:54 | wood  |   200
```

what am i trying to get is peak value in stock per day:

```
   booking_day |  art  | peak
   ------------+-------+-------
    2017-06-18 | wood  | 3000
    2017-06-16 | stone | 1000
    2017-06-19 | wood  | 2800
```

so for 18.06 highest amount of wood in stock would be 3000 (1000 + 2000); at the end of the day only 2700 (1000 + 2000 - 300) left

for 19.06 we start at 2700 wood from yesterday reaching peak with 2800 (2700 + 100); amount left at end of the day would be 2000 (2700 + 100 - 1000 + 200)

is it even possible with SQL? maybe i need another table to store daily amounts or something like that

Comment: Yep, I think so. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The idea of SO is you have a go at it, we help if you have a problem. It is not, you provide a specification and we write it for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might consider looking through the help section for helpful info on how to ask a question on SO that gets useful results, and the types of questions that are appropriate on SO. This is pretty trivial for MySQL. What have you tried? Do you want to display the net available per day or the results in your example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate a cumulative sum and then aggregate:

```
select date(booking_time), art, max(running_stock)
from (select t.*,
             (@s := if(@a = t.art, @s + weight,
                       if @a := t.art, weight, weight)
                      )
             ) as running_stock
      from t cross join
           (select @s := 0, @a := 0) params
      order by t.art, t.booking_time
     ) t
group by date(booking_time), art;
```